# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement in c# OleDb Exception cant spot the error

Tags: c#, ms-access, syntax-error, oledbexception

> **EXACT** duplicate of [Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement in c#
>   oledb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627552/syntax-error-in-insert-into-statement-in-c-oledb)

Hi I cant spot the error. Please help. There is an OleDb Exception due to a Syntax Error.
Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement OleDb Exception is unhandled.

```
    private OleDbConnection myCon;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myCon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=C.mdb");
    }

private void insertuser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            myCon.Open();
            cmd.Connection = myCon;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO User ([UserID], [Forename], [Surname], [DateOfBirth], [TargetWeight], [TargetCalories], [Height]) Values ('" + userid.Text + "' , '" + fname.Text + "' , '" + sname.Text + "' , '" + dob.Text + "' , '" + tarweight.Text + "' , '" + tarcal.Text + "' , '" + height.Text + "')";


            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myCon.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }



    }
```

Comment: Are you kidding us? Would you care to tell us what the error is?

Comment: Put brackets [] around the table name "User". It's a reserved word in SQL Server.

Comment: **Please** parameterize your query.

Comment: **EXACT** duplicate of [Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement in c# oledb?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627552/syntax-error-in-insert-into-statement-in-c-oledb)

Comment: You've just ask this very question a few minutes ago - don't keep asking the same question over and over again!

Comment: @BoltClock - not sure if that's the only thing wrong, so I didn't make it an answer. Completely agree with your parameterizing comment.

Comment: @Tim: Post it as an answer to the question this duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

What are the values you're attempting to insert?  Is height perhaps in feet and inches (5'10")?  In which case you'll have closed the string (') and will have a syntax error.

And I agree wholeheartedly with @Brennan Vincent.  Constructing raw SQL is not the way forward.

Answer (score 0):

If `TargetWeight`, `Height`, and `TargetCalories` are floating-point or integer values, they don't need to be surrounded by quotes in the SQL statement.

Also, not directly related to your question, but you should really consider using a parameterized query. Your code is very vulnerable to SQL injection.